# I'm using Api to display data

Tags: python, html, flask

**I'm trying to load character data with stats in my server but it seems it won't load and i have no idea why, i think the problem has to do with the Api**

There are 2 functions in this code one that collects character name ect with a transportID that i use in the second function to use it on the second Api so i can access the stats of the specific character

```
def character_data():
    url = "https://webapi.mir4global.com/nft/lists?listType=topTraded&page=1&languageCode=en"
    response = requests.get(url)
    characters = []
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        datas = data['data']['lists']

        class_images = {
            1: "warrior.webp",
            2: "mage.webp",
            3: "taoist.webp",
            4: "arbalist.webp",
            5: "lancer.webp",
            6: "darkist.webp"
        }

        for character_data in datas:
            info = character_data['info']
            name = info['characterName']
            price = info['price']
            power = info['powerScore']
            level = info['lv']
            seq = info['seq']
            character_class = info['class']
            Tran = info['transportID']
            classe = class_images.get(character_class, "unknown_class.webp")

            character_details = {
                "Character Name": name,
                "Level": level,
                "Power Score": power,
                "Character Price": price,
                "Character picture": classe,
                "link": "https://www.xdraco.com/nft/trade/" + str(seq),
                "transportID": Tran
            }

            characters.append(character_details)
    return characters
```

this is the second function where i collect stats of each character

```
def character_stats(characters):

    stats = []

    for character in characters:
        TransID = character['transportID']
        urls = "https://webapi.mir4global.com/nft/character/stats?transportID={}&languageCode=en".format(
            TransID)
        responses = requests.get(urls)
        if responses.status_code == 200:
            dataas = responses.json()
            datass = dataas['data']['lists']
            phys = datass[6].get("statValue")
            spell = datass[7].get("statValue")
            phys_def = datass[8].get("statValue")
            spell_def = datass[9].get("statValue")
            acc = datass[10].get("statValue")
            eva = datass[11].get('statValue')
            crit = datass[12].get('statValue')
            crit_eva = datass[13].get('statValue')

        stats_details = {
            "Phys Atk": phys,
            "Spell Atk": spell,
            "PHYS DEF": phys_def,
            "Spell DEF": spell_def,
            "Accuracy": acc,
            "EVA": eva,
            "CRIT": crit,
            "CRIT EVA": crit_eva
        }
        stats.append(stats_details)

    return stats


@app.route("/")
def home():
    characters = character_data()
    stats = character_stats(characters)

    return render_template("index.html", characters=characters, stats=stats)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**HTML CODE **

```
 {% for character, stat in zip(character_info, stats) %}
                <div class="character"> 
                    <div class="center">
                        <div class="name-container">
                            <img class="imag" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' +                           character['Character picture']) }}" alt="">
                            <ul>

                                <li class="lvl">{{ character["Level"] }}</li>
                                <li class="ps">{{ character["Power Score"] }}</li>
                                <li class="name">{{ character["Character Name"] }}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>{{ stat["Phys Atk"] }}</li>
                            <li>{{ stat["Spell Atk"] }}</li>
                            <li>{{ stat["PHYS DEF"] }}</li>
                            <li>{{ stat["Spell DEF"] }}</li>
                            <li>{{ stat["Accuracy"] }}</li>
                            <li>{{ stat["EVA"] }}</li>
                            <li>{{ stat["CRIT"] }}</li>
                            <li>{{ stat["CRIT EVA"] }}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="price" data-link="{{ character['link'] }}">
                            <p>{{ character["Character Price"] }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: That HTML will display your data, but it's not part of a `<form>`.  How do you expect to get the values back to the server?  Do you have Javascript for that?